# How to specify depth parameter for npm

Tags: node.js, npm

The NPM manual says you can specify `depth` as an *integer* parameter.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

I've tried the following, but none work.

```
$ npm --depth=1 list
$ npm --depth 1 list
$ npm depth 1 list
$ npm depth:1 list
$ npm depth=1 list
```

I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

params come after the command name, e.g.:

```
[user@host: ~/repo]$ npm list --depth=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the command first, then the options. `npm ls --depth 1`